# start ckeditor in source mode so it doesn't format text

Tags: ckeditor

Is there a simple way to initialize ckeditor in source mode so it won't format the content?

When I am saving certain code I save it in source mode and that works great, but to keep it from editing my code I need to track if it was saved in source mode and also load it in source mode to make it easier to edit information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.  It is really simple thankfully.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' ).config.startupMode = 'source';
</script>
```

Comment: I would recommend passing the config value directly to the `replace()` method: `CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', { startupMode: 'source' } );`. This way you're sure that it's set immediately.